# Page Curl on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

I look around for similar posts but didn't find a solution. I'm looking for a simple page turn animation (without finger tracking) like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vOYvaNhSHw

Is it possible to create or license it?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16):

This fragment of code do the trick:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.base.view cache:YES];

[user.view removeFromSuperview];
[base.view addSubview:home.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In this example the "user" viewcontroller is removed, and the "home" viewcontroller is added, with a pageflip like transition

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible.

Read the following blog tutorial.

http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/

http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html

http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html

Comment: The first link helped me find Apple's [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) which provides an SDK specific way of implementing pages with scrolling with page curl.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old and closed question but if someone is looking for a working implementation look at this:

Newer:
[iOS-PageCurl-OpenGL](https://github.com/bachelora/iOS-PageCurl-OpenGL)

Older:
[XBPageCurl project](https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl)

Comment: Also do not forget to dig into source code and implement the finish of animation by yourself... This project has awesome graphics, but if you want to curl from one page to another, you simply can't do this without what i was saying earlier

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown`. Example shown in this question:

[curl down transition for adding an UIView to a superview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341603/curl-down-transition-for-adding-an-uiview-to-a-superview)

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for something similar I have found out that for some people (like me itself) [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) did the trick with transition style `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` ideally. If you want to see what you can achieve using this component take a look at iBooks app and try to turn the page. Very simple to use, great effect.

Page cant be rotated programatically and by a pan gesture which gives very page rotation/turning like feel.