# ios page curl to show view controller

Tags: ios

[image]

Hi I want to make the map view to look like that. I want to make the bottom right like that and when I click on it, it launches a modal view controller.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to use photoshop and current a button that has the top and bottom transparency and use it as an button over your view.

Answer (score 2):

See this Question(+Answer of course ^^): [Page Curl on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435547/page-curl-on-ios)