# programmatically load image at coordinate

Tags: ios

[image]

Hi I want to load a square image (the page curl) as seen in the lower right corner programmatically when the view controller loads.

How to do this?

Comment: This looks almost exactly like a question you asked two hours earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206459/ios-page-curl-to-show-view-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `UIImageView` as a subview and set the appropriate frame.

Comment: @SuperString It's not harder than creating, adding and positioning any view. I don't see how you could develop an iOS application without this knowledge.