# Page flip from middle of the screen in iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

How can I achieve the effect shown in the below link?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oknMWvRO2XE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out by Ole Bagemann - http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/

http://iosdevgoodies.joostschuur.com/ibook-style-page-curl-animations

[Page Curl on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435547/page-curl-on-ios)