# Partial page curl by pan gesture like in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, ios5, presentmodalviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to **partly** display a view controller exactly like

> UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl

,
but instead of the curling animation i want to curl the view by a pan gesture

My goal is to get the same affect like when using UIPageViewController to switch between ViewControllers by dragging\curling the page according to the user touches (not a swipe gesture).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435547/page-curl-on-ios. The code you want is in [XBPageCurl](https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl)