# I want to do curl on my PDF page in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdfviewer

I want to do curl on my PDF page in iOS.
I have load my PDF to a web view, but I want to give effect on PDF page, so help me.
I want to swipe to page turn and with swipe it curl.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"paper" ofType:@"pdf"];
_webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

NSURL *myUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
[_webView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

and in advance thanks to helper.

Comment: So, what's your problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435547/page-curl-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that through UIPageViewController-PDF (follow full instructions from the github page, though):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
[self presentViewController:page animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Loading PDF in UIWebview is not the right way. Use UIPageViewController to load  PDF with curl animation.

Comment: i want to give curl effect. With this code i only load pdf in my webView

Comment: Curl animation is inbuilt feature in UIPageViewController. You can check this link http://devmonologue.com/ios/tutorials/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: I have given an above link. Please look it and study, how to use it.Specify what error you are getting. Don't get upset.