# Animation like Paging effect on UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiswipegesturerecognizer

**-** The functionality which is required by client is already implemented using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` but I am not able to give animation which is needed.

**-** I want the animation of dragging image as its in paging effect of UIScrollview.

**Let me explain in detail:**

**-** In `UIScrollView` with **paging enabled**, when we drag image, it will be dragged behind our finger not just slight swipe.

**-** In my case its moving away as soon as the finger moves over the image, so I want the animation of image to be sliding as far as my fingers moves and on leaving it should move away.

-Friends, I don't want curl effect but I only want swipping functionality as far as my finger moves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435547/page-curl-on-ios

Comment: Thanks for your reply but you have misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at this repository and you can find what you need if you edit this repository code and use PanGestureRecognizer instead of SwipeGestureRecognizer in this repository.

```
https://github.com/agrawalmahesh/MKImageSlideshow
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable paging property of the `UIScrollView`.