# How rotate .transitionCurlDown animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

How rotate .transitionCurlDown animation to get the rotation of the book sheet (horizontal, not vertical), same as this:

[image]

There is vertical page curl animation:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.myView, duration: 0.7, 
options: .transitionCurlDown, animations: {
})
```

Important: I don't want to use transition between UIViewControllers or UIPageControllers, I want to apply animation on UIView on the current screen.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435547/page-curl-on-ios ?

Comment: @matt No, I need really working Curl Left animation. There is no working answer in the previous question.

Comment: Check out using a page view controller. It is one of the options for transitions

Comment: @agibson007I know I can do that. But I need an option without switching between any controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
func animatePage(side: PageCurl, textView: UITextView) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        let animation = CATransition()
        animation.duration = 0.3
        animation.startProgress = 0.0
        animation.endProgress = 1
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        animation.type = CATransitionType(rawValue: "pageCurl")
        if side == .left {
            animation.subtype = CATransitionSubtype(rawValue: "fromLeft")
        } else {
            animation.subtype = CATransitionSubtype(rawValue: "fromRight")
        }
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        textView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "pageFlipAnimation")
    })
}
```

Use:

```
animatePage(side: .left, textView: myTextView)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one note to the accepted answer. If you want to use it like book flip animation, change your `imageView.image` from cover to page, for example, before this line `animatePage(side: .left, textView: myTextView)`

So if you have `cover` image and `page` image, your code should be like:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "page.png")
animatePage(side: .right, view: imageView)
```

And it will give your a nice looking flip animation from cover to page